# Calculate total for multiple entries to a field

Tags: php, sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Employee_id  dev_hours Pm_hours
1                2         2
1                3         3
2                3         3
3                2         1 
3                1         1
```

How would I used php to find the total hours that each individual employee had worked on? For example employee 1 would have worked for a total of 10 hours and employee 3 worked for a total of 5 hours?

Comment: Clues: SUM(dev_hours + Pm_hours) and GROUP BY Employee_id

Comment: Would this be a MySql database?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)and [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). Try:

```
SELECT Employee_id, SUM(dev_hours + Pm_hours) as total_hours FROM tbl GROUP BY Employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation taken from w3 schools PHP guide here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server","user","password");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Employee_id, SUM(dev_hours + Pm_hours) as Hours FROM EmployeeTable GROUP BY Employee_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['Employee_id'] . " " . $row['Hours'];
  echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```